# elmah.axd not found on IIS 8.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, iis-8, elmah.mvc

Ok..I know this is asked many times and I looked bunch of questions and answers about this and nothing worked for me and I am getting crazy. I am trying to put elmah to my asp.net mvc 5 application and I can't get it to work. I keep getting not found error.

My config for elmah is:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandler" value="false" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandleErrorFilter" value="false" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.requiresAuthentication" value="false" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.IgnoreDefaultRoute" value="false" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.allowedRoles" value="*" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.allowedUsers" value="*" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.route" value="elmah" />
  </appSettings>

<sectionGroup name="elmah">
      <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
    </sectionGroup>

  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On"></customErrors>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" />
    </httpModules>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>



 <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add name="Elmah" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
    </handlers>
    <modules>
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah"/>
      <!--<add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />-->
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <elmah>
    <security allowRemoteAccess="1" />
    <errorLog type="Elmah.XmlFileErrorLog, Elmah" logPath="~/App_Data/elmah" />
  </elmah>
```

and yes i have ignored .axd in my rout config..

routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

What am I missing ??

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a MIME type for that extension in IIS:

To define a MIME type for a specific extension, follow these steps:

Open the IIS Microsoft Management Console (MMC), right-click the local computer name, and then click Properties.
Click HTTP Headers.
Click MIME Types.
Click New.
In the Extension box, type the file name extension that you want (for example, .axed)
In the MIME Type box, type application/octet-stream.
Apply the new settings. Note that you must restart the World Wide Web Publishing Service or wait for the worker process to recycle for the changes to take effect. In this example, IIS now serves files with the .axed extension.